# Adding Custom options to Menu Items in Wordpress Menu Manager

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking forward to add custom options to Menus block in wordpress.

For e.g. When we add a menu item,with menu manager in WP, there are few text boxes appear inside the collapsible panel, such as Title, Label, etc.

I want to add a custom option of mine into the menu items, by developing a plugin.

I went through the core code, but couldn't find any hook, that could be available to accomplish this.